# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Block_Styles_Registry'

Tags: php, filters, hooks, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script

I am having some issues determining the solution to this problem below. The website was sent to our team to fix.

Turned on error reporting in `wp-config.php`:
`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

> WordPress version: 5.3.2
> PHP version: 7.2

WordPress Theme:
[Grow Pro](https://www.thinkupthemes.com/themes/grow/)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Block_Styles_Registry' not 
found in /home/website/public_html/clientsite.com/wp-includes/script- 
loader.php:2902 Stack trace: #0 
/home/website/public_html/clientsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp- 
hook.php(288): enqueue_block_styles_assets('') #1 
/home/website/public_html/clientsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp- 
hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 
/home/website/public_html/clientsite.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): 
WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 
/home/website/public_html/clientsite.com/wp-includes/script- 
loader.php(2856): do_action('enqueue_block_a...') #4 
/home/website/public_html/clientsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp- 
hook.php(288): wp_common_block_scripts_and_styles('') #5 
/home/website/public_html/clientsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp- 
hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #6 
/home/website/public_html/clientsite.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): 
WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #7 /home/website/public_html/ir in 
/home/website/public_html/clientsite.com/wp-includes/script-loader.php 
on line 2902
```

There has been a critical error on your website.

[Learn more about debugging in WordPress.](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)

---

For privacy reasons, I wouldn't be sharing the live website link.

Any help with resolving these errors would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Nick Hiebert

Comment: Did you recently update WP? Sounds like [this issue](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fixing-fatal-error-after-5-30-update/).

Comment: @kero sounded very similar. Managed to figure out the issue.

Comment: This may help you. https://wphuntrz.com/d/7-uncaught-error-class-wp-block-styles-registry-not-found

Comment: @jogesh_pi we're looking at the issues with the WordPress update as we speak. So I'll report back what ends up being the fix.

Answer (score 0):

From this post on WordPress.org "[Fixing fatal error after 5.30 update](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fixing-fatal-error-after-5-30-update/)", it mentions issues with Gutenberg.

I installed the [Glutenberg](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/) plugin and the website is now loading properly.

Hope this comes to use for the future for anyone else!

Comment: Watch out, I don't believe you actually fixed your problem and just avoided the error message. The post you mention there is mine, and I **did not** have the message `Class 'WP_Block_Styles_Registry' not 
found` but another one. Your error probably comes from an incomplete update. Other stuff may break until you fix this!

Comment: @kero Sounds good, it is likely a WordPress update issue. I'll report back the actual fix to this once it's resolved.